# Creating eth0 with consistent network device naming

Tags: arch-linux, devices, network-interface

From my understanding, Arch Linux uses [Consistent Network Device Naming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_Network_Device_Naming) where the network devices are no longer named eth0, eth1, etc.

I use the proprietary MATLAB software which requires a device eth0 for [activation](https://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-661QJD/index.html?solution=1-661QJD). As a work around they suggest turning off consistent network device naming [here](https://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-EUTG50/index.html?solution=1-EUTG50). I don't think this will work in Arch, but maybe I am wrong, and I am not sure that is a good idea even if it does work.

Is it possible to create a dummy eth0 device to fool the MATLAB activation software? Note that this is not intended to, and I don't believe that it does, violate any licensing agreements with MATLAB/The MathWorks.

Comment: 6 years later, changed `enp0s31f6` to `eth0` and matlab activates.

Comment: `nmcli connection modify enp0s31f6 connection.interface-name eth0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried creating a blank `/etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-name-slot.rules`?

Since Udev v197, udev has implemented predictable network interface names, by creating a blank file in that path then rebooting, you should have your interface names back to what they were.

**Reference:** [Predictable Network Interface Names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames)

Answer (score 4):

Short-term solution:

```
% sudo modprobe dummy
% sudo ip l set dev dummy0 name MyEth11
% sudo ip ad ad 192.168.255.254/30 dev MyEth11
% ip ad show dev MyEth11
14: MyEth11: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN 
    link/ether 6e:73:12:ad:db:8e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.255.254/30 scope global MyEth11
% sudo ip l set MyEth11 up
```

Comment: Interesting. But how is this interface connected to the real world? The application probably binds to this interface (or its address).

Comment: For MATLAB I don't need to bring the dummy interface up, but I did need to clone my mac address with `ip link set dev MyEth11 address xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`. My guess is bringing the dummy interface up would cause major havoc. Can I add this as a script in `/etc/profile.d/` to make it persistent?

Comment: This can be a script, of course, placed, for e. g., into `/etc/rc.local`. But I said "single term" intentionally meaning that different distros have different "proper" ways to set such things up.

Comment: And nope, having two NICs with the same MAC addresses, but in different network segments isn't a havoc.

Answer (score 4):

Since udev v209 this is done the following way:

```
$ sudo ln -s /dev/null /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
```

See also, [Predictable Network Interface Names - I don't like this, how do I disable this?](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/#idontlikethishowdoidisablethis)

**NOTE:** In that same section a couple of other methods are mentioned as well:

> You basically have four options:
>
> 1. You disable the assignment of fixed names, so that the unpredictable
>      kernel names are used again. For this, simply mask udev's rule file
>      for the default policy:
>
>    ```
>    $ ln -s /dev/null /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
>    ```
> 2. You create your own manual naming scheme, for example by naming your interfaces "internet0", "dmz0" or "lan0". For that create your
>      own .link files in /etc/systemd/network/, that choose an explicit name
>      or a better naming scheme for one, some, or all of your interfaces.
>      See systemd.link(5) for more information.
>
> You pass the net.ifnames=0 on the kernel command line