# Can renaming a network device cause race conditions?

Tags: arch-linux, devices, networkcard

Arch uses predictable network interface names. MATLAB licenses are linked to the MAC address of eth0, so I need to rename one of my devices eth0. In a machines with only one NIC I can just turn off [consistent naming](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74039/creating-eth0-with-consistent-network-device-naming), but in machines with multiple NICs it seems like it is desirable to keep consistent naming and just rename the device I care about to eth0 (it is still consistent after all). The [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration#Change_device_name) suggests creating a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-network.rules` with

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff", NAME="net1"
```

but the wiki includes the disclaimer:

> When choosing the static names it should be avoided to use names in the format of "ethX" and "wlanX", because this may lead to race conditions between the kernel and udev during boot.

For ethX with X greater than 0, I can see how this might be a problem, but for eth0 it seems like the kernel would have already used eth0 by the time the rename happens. So on a system with multiple NICs, do I have to worry about renaming a device to eth0?

Alternatively, can I rename the device once I am fully booted and the network is online?

Answer (score 0):

With just the one NIC I do not see why you'd have to worry about this disclaimer. You could rename the device, but be prepared to lose connectivity. I generally try to avoid this and get the naming squared away via the system's boot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have multiple NICs. I want to rename one NIC to be eth0. I thought that renaming to eth0 might prevent a collision since the kernel would have already used eth0 before the rename can happen. If instead I was trying to rename eth1, then the kernel might not have already used eth1 and a collision would happen. I edited the question to try and make it clearer.